# PHP Mail and Database Logging

Tags: php, sql, email, sendmail

So I'm trying to set something up where it logs in a database and emails me when a person from a referrer containing a certain phrase in that referrer, but it's not emailing me or entering anything into my database. No errors shot either. I set up mail in my php.ini and I have an SMTP server installed and all.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$to = 'email';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'User with the IP "' . $ip . ' from darkbox.' . "\r\n" . 'Do not respond to this email.';
$headers = 'From: darkbox@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: no one' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if (strpos($ref,'darkbox') == true) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    } else {
        // All good, chief.
    }
     // Timestamp
    $date=date_create();
    date_timestamp_get($date);
    $time = date_format($date,"U = Y-m-d H:i:s");

$host = 'localhost:3306';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        // All good bruv.
    }
$sql = 'INSERT INTO darkbox_logs '.
       '(IP,Referrer,Datetime) '.
       'VALUES ( ' . $ip . ', ' . $ref . ', ' . $time . ')';

mysql_select_db('darkbox_logs');
$ping = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $ping ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        // all good
    }
echo "Data logged";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi / PDO instead

Comment: I was using mysqli and it was the same problem so I went to MySQL.

Comment: Have you checked that $ip, $ref and $time contain values? Does your $time variable match your database column? Go back to mysqli! Also try turning errors on http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: They all should contain values, how would I check? And yea, it does.

Comment: Echoing them doesn't work. I get a blank white page.

Comment: @Cody **absolutely incorrect**! It's developer's responsibility to solve problems, not avoid problems by using deprecated libraries.

Comment: I just figured it might work.